# Can I partly bind a tuple using a structured binding with fewer elements than the size of the tuple?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm surprised I couldn't find this question asked anywhere. Also it would seem this language feature would not be hard to implement (may be wrong though).

```
const auto [a, b] = function_returning_triplet(); // error: only 2 names provided for structured binding
```

Comment: Answer is no...